# I need to run cronjob every 5 minutes plus offset time

Tags: php, cron

Currently my cron job is scheduled to every 5 minutes.

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://localhost/aa_portal/refresh_id.php
```

currently this schedule is running every 5 minutes

> Example : 12.00AM, 12.05AM, 12.10AM, ....

I need to run this Job every 5 minutes by 2 min gap

> Example : 12.02AM, 12.07AM, 12.12AM, ....

Can I change this cron job command to full fill this requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the KISS principle you could just list the minutes
2,7,12,17,22,27,32,37,42,47,52,57

Example:

```
2,7,12,17,22,27,32,37,42,47,52,57 * * * * curl http://localhost/aa_portal/refresh_id.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Debian 11 using cron.

```
2-59/5 * * * * myCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

0 2-59/5 * * * ? this worked for me, but it's java